# Converter Json para um tipo Long

Tags: javascript, json, localstorage

Tenho um objeto Json vindo do localStorage e preciso que  ele seja convertido para um tipo Long, no caso `entidadeId`

```
idEntidade = localStorage.getItem("idEntidade");
var entidadeId = JSON.parse(idEntidade);
```

Comment: _" seja convertido para um Long"_ - o que é um "Long"?

Comment: do tipo Long, tal como int

Comment: Isso não é `Java`?

Comment: To fazendo pelo javaScript

Comment: Não conheço esse tipo _Long_.

Comment: @EduardoKrakhecke ok. No JavaScript não há _Long_. Essa string que queres converter tem texto ou só numeros?

Comment: @Sergio tem só um numero

Comment: Então a resposta do Breno faz o que precisas.

Comment: Mesmo o Long não existindo, fiquei curioso pra saber qual seria o propósito em converter? Ficaria muito grato em saber :)

Comment: @DvD é porque o `localStorage` guarda tudo em _String_.

Comment: @Sergio Verdade. Valeu!

Comment: @DvD é que eu estou guardando um parâmetro que é um id no localStorage, e nesse momento eu preciso passar ele em uma requisição,e a requisição pede um tipo Long, porém ele é uma String no localStorage, então precisei converter.

Comment: Entendi. MAs esse Long vc tirou de onde, do Java?

Comment: @DvD sim, está vindo do Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como JavaScript não é uma linguagem fortemente tipada, sugiro você apenas converter sua váriavel para um número, da seguinte forma:

```
idEntidade = Number(localStorage.getItem("idEntidade"));
```